# How can I test a single void method inside a class with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I've been searching around a bit for an answer to this but I can't seem to find anything concrete.

Let's assume I have a class with multiple methods and in side that class I have a single method which is only called from a Javascript request. That method has a few other method calls inside it. However, it has no return value and no parameters. I want to test a few cases for that method. Here's an example:

```
public function myMethod(): void{
    $dataArray = request()->data;
    $service = $this->doMath();
    $start = $service->getStart($paramA, $paramB);

    // Couple computations here to get $someData
    $end = $someData;

    $this->final['start'] = $start;
    $this->final['end'] = $end;
}
```

So essentially, I want to write some test for `myMethod()` and give it different values for `$paramA` and `$paramB` and assert that `$this->final` has the right/wrong outputs.

What would be the way to go about this?

Comment: Can you not just instantiate the class, run the method, and test the property values? See also https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests

Comment: @miken32 I was thinking of doing just that. So I would instantiate is, have some data in an array and test the values.  How would that work with PHPUnit though (can't find anything in the docs)? Or I guess a better question is, is that actually a proper way of testing? I am onboarding on a codebase, and there is not really any unit test for this class and that method is just there doing one thing. Pretty confused as it's a quite critical piece of code which needs to be properly tested.

Comment: Just use the standard assertions to test whatever you want. The link includes details on how you can populate the request object, or you could make the method accept optional parameters, falling back to the request if they aren't provided. It's not great practice to rely on the request object outside of a controller context anyway, so including the data as parameter would make testing easier and improve the code.